# One to many relationship & 2nf

Tags: normalization

Does the table design below violate the 2nf normalization principle or any normalization rule ( ie. 1nf,3nf)? I have read that 2nf is violated only if there are non key attributes that are  functionally dependent to some composite keys rather than to the whole composite keys. However, I have read in other sources that the design such as the one below is a violation of 2nf simply because certain attribute value appears in multiple rows for certain key. However, phone is entirely dependent to user, and I don't understand how this violates 2nf.

---

```
record_id       name          phone
1               john         6789678
2               john         3879767
```

Comment: Are both `john` the same?

Comment: Yes. He has two phone numbers.

Answer (score -1):

If (like you said in your remark) `john` has 2 phone numbers then it is a 1:n relation. In that case you need to store the phone in a separate table. You end up with:

*Person*

```
person_id (PK)
name
```

*Phone*

```
record_id (PK)
person_id (FK)
phone
```

You can leave out `record_id` and use `person_id` and `phone` as a primary key.

Since a `person` can have multiple `phone` you must 'double' the `person` information for every `phone`. In your example this is only `name` so is does not seem to be such a problem but imagine that a `person` has 100 `phone` and you must change his `name`. You will have to change all 100 rows.

Also think about 2 `person` that share the same `phone`.

Comment: But how does the original table violate 2nf? Or does it violate any specific normalization rule? I cannot find any specific normalization form which it may have violated. Thanks